# Elegant way to strip values in brackets in Python

Tags: python

```
Line = "A[0x04] Va   [0xf]
```

How do I split lines like these down into two variables containing `0x04` and `0xf`?

Attempted solution:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    line.strip("[]").split
```

Comment: I am missing the c/c++'s sscanf() function here :-)

Comment: On another note, don't use capitals for variable names. See PEP 8: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a list comprehension:

```
>>> Line = "A[0x04] Va   [0xf]"
>>> [x.partition(']')[0] for x in Line.split('[') if ']' in x]
['0x04', '0xf']
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use [`re.findall`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
>>> from re import findall
>>> Line = "A[0x04] Va   [0xf] "
>>> findall("\[([^\]]*)\]", Line)
['0x04', '0xf']
>>> x,y = findall("\[([^\]]*)\]", Line)
>>> x
'0x04'
>>> y
'0xf'
>>>
```

Below is a breakdown of the Regex pattern:

```
\[        # [
([^\]]*)  # Capture group to get zero or more characters that are not ]
\]        # ]
```

Comment: I would prefer `\[[^\]]*\]`.

Comment: Still going to need the capturing group.

Comment: @F.J not for findall.  Works without it.  Not sure why :)

Comment: @MK. - Without the capture group, you will get `['[0x04]', '[0xf]']`.  The OP wanted `['0x04', '0xf']`.

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
re.findall("\[[^\]]*\]", Line)
```

Comment: I like this one. I also liked the list comprehension and could only pick one

Answer (score 1):

```
In [36]: %paste
answer = []
take = False
line = "A[0x04] Va   [0xf] "
start = 0
for i,char in enumerate(line):
    if not take:
        if char == '[' :
            take = True
            start = i+1
    else:
        if char == ']':
            take = False
            answer.append(line[start:i])

## -- End pasted text --

In [37]: answer
Out[37]: ['0x04', '0xf']
```

Comment: Works, but I hardly find it elegant. Needless regex is good to avoid, but in this case it could very well be the right tool for the right job.